# Capture ID and Column_Check Value On checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I am using JQuery DataTables to allow the user the ability to set stores as Active (checked) or inActive (not checked).  I need a way of capturing the ID (hidden column) and the check value (checked or unchecked).

I have this function which I thought would do it, but nothing is being written tot he console.

```
$('#tblAddRemoveStores').on('change', 'tbody input.editor-active', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    cb = $(this).prop('checked');
    console.log(data.id + ' ' + cb);
});
```

And here is a codepen of full syntax that illustrates what I'm after.
https://codepen.io/chalupabatman/pen/VwwyaYv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tblAddRemoveStores').on('change', 'tbody input.checkbox_checked', function () {

   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     console.log("checked");
   } else {
     console.log("unchecked");
   }  

  var id =  $(this).parent().parent().find("td:first").text();
  console.log(id);    
});
```

https://codepen.io/tshenolo/pen/abbEmzY

Not the best solution but it will get you started. I hope this helps.

Comment: one thing I noticed is that if the user unchecks, then checks again - it console.log() shows unchecked each time even tho it is now checked?